# How does the inverse mean curvature flow start with minimal surface?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I am unclear how the inverse mean curvature flow starts with a minimal surface. If there is some point $p$ with mean curvature $H(P)=0$, how should we treat this problem and let the flow start?

Comment: Why do you believe that the flow starts at such a point or for a minimal surface?

Comment: If the initial hypersurface for inverse mean curvature flow is the minimal surface, the penrose inequality could be proved with the monotonicity of the Hawking mass. I am a little confused about the beginning of the flow and want to understand that more clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't clear exactly what sort of initial conditions you're requiring.

The difficulty with minimal initial conditions is part of the reason why it was an amazing result when Huisken--Ilmanen [constructed](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1090349447) a "weak inverse mean curvature flow" which

(1) Can start at a minimal surface (technically, for certain things to work nicely, it should be outer-minimizing)

(2) Exists for all time in an asymptotically flat manifold.

AND

(3) Still satisfies Geroch monotonicity, i.e. the Hawking mass is monotone along the flow.

That one could find a "flow" which satisfies (1) and (2) while still keeping (3) is incredible.

Their paper is very readable, although quite long, so I'd recommend that you take a look at it, rather than I try to explain the ideas here.

---

**EDIT:** I've added some more information below. Its not totally clear what your motivation for the question is; if you add more information perhaps I can answer your question better.

---

It is sometimes possible to define a classical flow which starts at a minimal surface. For example, in the Riemannian Schwarzschild metric 
$$
g = \left(1+\frac{2m}{r}\right)^4 \delta,
$$
on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$, there is a inverse mean curvauture flow $\Sigma_t = \{r(t)\}\times \mathbb{S}^2$ defined for $t>0$, where $\lim_{t\searrow 0} r(t) = m/2$. I'll leave it to you to compute the associated ODE (HINT: the easiest way is to use the fact that $|\Sigma_t|=e^t|\Sigma_0|$.

Be very careful with what I mean here for $t=0$. In particular, the PDE is not satisfied for $t=0$, just $t>0$.

---

Here are some results about the classical flow:

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1064876

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1082861

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1753358

Comment: Does that mean that in the classic condition we have admitted the existence of the inverse mean curvature flow starting from a minimal surface?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question, can you rephrase it?

Comment: I am wondering that in classic case, we admitted this flow could be start from a minimal surface and using this initial condition to make other conclusions. But till Huisken and Ilmanen, people then actually make it clear with weak inverse mean curvature flow. is it right?

Comment: @Jer, I'm sorry but I am having difficulty understanding your question. Could you please clarify? In particular, by "we admit" do you mean "we assumed"?

Comment: Oh,I am sorry...that's right. I should use "we assumed"

Comment: Ok, I will compute the inverse mean curvature flow relevant to the Riemannian Schwarzschild metric and read the papers you recommended to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Could you tell me what do you mean by "outer minimizing" in your answer? Does it mean the set is a supersolution with obstacle inside? I learned in your first reference that star-shaped hypersurfaces evolve into a sphere by inverse mean curvature flow, so is it true that the "outer minimizing" set also evolve to a sphere by inverse mean curvature flow? Thanks!

Comment: An open set $\Omega$ (with finite perimeter) is outer minimizing if for any open set $\Omega'$ containing $\Omega$, we have $|\partial^*\Omega|\leq |\partial^*\Omega'|$. For your second question, in the asymptotically flat case, this is true (see http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1916951), but not in general (see http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2629514).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. I looked through Huisken's paper (2001) a little bit, but I couldn't find the asymptotic convergence result of an outward minimizing surface under mean curvature flow.  Yes, the solution exists for all time if initial surface is outward minimizing, but why it must converge to a sphere? Is it just an implication from some result? Could you please specify a page? Also why an outward minimizing surface must be a level surface of some function? I'm getting more and more confused. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Huisken and Ilmanen's paper is indeed a hard read, but I find that I learn something each time I open it. Lemma 7.1 in HI proves that in an AF manifold, the solutions become spherical in the blown-down sense. Some further information is also available in Lemma 7.4. If you want more information about the asymptotics of the flow, HI have written a followup paper (that only considers Euclidean space) "higher regularity of the inverse mean curvature flow" http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:52807/component/escidoc:52808/JDG-80-3-A3-huisken.pdf  ...

Comment: ... but it might be best to stick with their first paper so as to not get confused.

Comment: As for your second question, "why is an outward minimizing surface the level set of a function" ? Note that (assuming a subsolution at infinity) given any precompact open set E_0 with smooth boundary, HI produce a weak solution to IMCF in their sense (Theorem 3.1). Note that this produces a function u so that int{u<=0} is the outer minimizing hull of E_0. ...

Comment: .... This can be seen from property 1.4. note that huisken ilmanen only consider flows from smooth initial data, since they can use their approximation theory (Lemma 5.6) to get information about C^1,1 outer minimizing hulls, which is what they actually need for part of the penrose inequality

Comment: btw, you are free to contact me by email (found on my website, linked from my profile) if you would like answers longer than 500 characters

Comment: Thank you so much! After spending a day I eventually understood a little bit. So the key is defining a variational solution of inverse mean curvature flow, and then prove the monotonicity of Hawking mass is preserved even at jumps. Of course there are a lot of difficulties to welcome, but now I can get the picture. Previously it's just too hard for me to picture the jump case, but since the solution is variational sense, the jump really works. This is a genius trick. The paper is hard to read, but I can understand little by little now.

Comment: If I have more questions, I'll definitely contact you by email. It's so kind of you to be such patient and helpful!